# Drop Down UIView With Buttons

Tags: objective-c, animation, button, uiview

Okay, so I want to make a menu that expands down at the current touch location. I achieve this by adding my menuView with a height of 1 and then changing the height to my desired one like this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:NULL context:nil];          
CGRect fullRect;
fullRect = CGRectMake(menuView.frame.origin.x, menuView.frame.origin.y, 290, 180);
menuView.frame = fullRect;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Now the problem is that there are 4 buttons in this menuView and these buttons appear first and then the menuView expands down under them. Any ideas how to make the buttons appear *with* the menuView and not before it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `menuView.clipsToBounds = YES` so the buttons are not shown outside the bounds of your `menuView` while it is expanding.

I would also add the following to have a fade-in effect for your buttons.

```
button1.alpha = 0.0; // Do this for each button before the [UIView beginAnimations];

button1.alpha = 1.0; // Do this during the animation block.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Block animation instead. That way, you can make the buttons appear during or after the animation easily. Try something like:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                       animations:^{ 
                         CGRect newRect = menuView.frame;
                         menuView.size.height += 289;
                         menuView.frame = newRect;
                       }
                       completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                                          animations:^{ 
                                            button.hidden = NO;
                                          } 
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                            ;
                                          }];
                       }];
```

This will make the button stop hiding at the end of the animation. Of course, you could add more blocks in the completion block to handle more animations, and it is easy to customize this. Hope that helps!

Comment: The `hidden` property is not animatable. `alpha` (opacity) is animatable, but you have to make sure that the alpha of the buttons is 0.0 (transparent) before you set it to 1.0 (opaque); otherwise, it won't animate.

Comment: You'll notice that setting button.hidden = NO is in the completion block, meaning it will happen AFTER the animation. You are right if you want to make the button fade, you will have to set the alpha value, but in my example, I just wanted it to appear at the end.